# Can't use http requests for portainer.io [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: docker, api, rest, ssl, portainer

So I was tasked with writing a program that would interact with portainer.io's API. The problem is though, that I get the error :

> Max retries exceeded with url: /api/auth (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

An example would look like:

```
import requests

URL = "https://localhost:9443"

data_auth = {
  "password": "password",
  "username": "username"
}

url_auth = URL + "/api/auth"

auth_response = requests.post(url_auth, data_auth)

print(auth_response)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error ? Should I create my own SSL certificate ? I am lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests` can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set  verify to False.

```
requests.get('https://localhost:9443', verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

Now understand this is *bad*, you should never ignore your SSL certs. But for development locally this is how to get past it.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the tip. I'll try to use it because I tried everything and couldn't get past the error. Sorry for the late replay though.